# How to convert existing Eclipse-based web application to Spring security

Tags: spring-security

I have an existing, eclipse based web servlet  application that authenticates using http basic authentication. I am looking to convert this to Spring based security. I understand what has to be done programatically, but am having problems with the details of configuring the project itself in eclipse. I am using the Spring STS toolkit, and I am able to successfully import one of the Spring Security sample apps (openid-xml) and it works fine.

My existing application also works properly when run under STS, but without Spring support

I would like a recommendation for either a tutorial on making this conversion, or some useful advice. For example, is it easier to

a) create a new Spring application and try to migrate my existing code into it, or b) try to convert my code by importing the various spring libraries, etc? c) convert my existing app to use maven instead of eclipse (Spring just doesn't seem to want to work without maven, and i am at a loss here) - naturally, I have no idea how to do this.

Any advice will be most gratefully received, after a day of hit and miss frustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered my own question, and will try to provide some details for those who may be having the same problem.

First, there is some relatively useless info available on stackoverflow, but some good stuff as well.

This (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14867188/1374167) is completely wrong.  It is certainly possible to secure a servlet with Spring Security.  The trick is to realize that you are going to have to use Maven and Gradle to build the libraries for Spring and Spring Security.

Once you have built these jar files, you simply import them into Eclipse (it doesn't really seem to matter which version) and set up your web.xml and security contraints.

I used [this](http://www.swview.org/sites/swview.org/files/JSFSpringSecurityWebApp.zip) project as a starting point.  It's not perfect, but it got me on the right track, after I updated the spring and spring security jar files.  The full blog post is [here](http://www.swview.org/blog/using-spring-security-your-java-web-application)

I had a frustrating experience getting to this point but I hope this information will help others.  It's quite simple once you understand what to do.